# Please explain this non-intuitive behavior in Scala regexp pattern matching

Tags: regex, scala

Why is the matching behavior different for the same matcher?

```
val str = "project git commit: da2837ec0a"

val Expr = "([a-f0-9]{10})$".r 

scala> str match { case Pattern(c) => c; case _ => "no match" }
res30: String = no match

scala> (Pattern findFirstIn str).get
res31: String = da2837ec0a
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use regular expressions with pattern matching, you must match the *entire* string. If this behaviour is not desired, you can make it an *unanchored* regular expression thus: `val Pattern = "whatever".r.unanchored`

In contrast, `findFirstIn` looks for a match anywhere within the string – and so doesn't require `unanchored` for this to match in your example.

This is documented in the [API reference](http://scala-lang.org/api/) which is often helpful for questions like these.